# How to use ADSBACKUP.EXE without password

Tags: advantage-database-server

I want to backup an **Advantage Database Server 11.10** with **ADSBACKUP.EXE** however I can't get it to work. It looks like the source path is interpreted as password, but we don't have an **ADSSYS** password.

When I try:

```
adsbackup.exe -p C:\Database\db.add E:\
```

I get

```
Missing argument, no destination path given
Backup arguments:
Source path: E:\
Destination path: NULL
```

When I leave the **-p** parameter out:

```
adsbackup.exe C:\Database\db.add E:\
```

I get:

```
Error 7078:  The Advantage Database Server cannot authenticate the user.  Make sure the user name and password are correct.  axServerConnect
```

I'm following: https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/mergedProjects/devguide/part1point5/creating_a_backup_using_adsbackup_exe.htm

---

**Update after comment Jens**

I already tired empty passwords in the parameter with `''`, `""` or even `NULL`. Neither worked.

When I try to run the backup through `asqlcmd.exe` I get (I'm logged in to the server by RDP):

```
Error: 5185 Error 5185:  Local server connections are restricted in this environment. See the 5185 error code documentation for details.  axServerConnect
```

This happens while we have `MTIER_LOCAL_CONNECTIONS=1` in `ADS.INI`.

And when I try the query in **Advantage Data Architect** I can't connect as `AdSys`:[image]

Could it be that there IS a password for `AdSys`, even when the vendor says it's not? Or am having some complete other problem?

Comment: You are using an UNC path there in your Connection Path, but you set the ServerType to local. If you are running an ADS Server, you should set the ServerType to remote.

Comment: Your first priority should indeed be to get it working from ARC (Advantage Data Architect).

Comment: One thing you can also try is to copy the whole Database directory to a local drive and connect through the local ServerType setting with a local ConnectPath. This will take the remote ADS server (if there is any) out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried some things in ARC: If I make a local connection I get the error that backups are not supported on local connections. If I try to login with adssys and set the option "use blank password" it can't authenticate, so I still think there is a password required that I don't know. If I connect without username I can see the tables but get an error saying I'm not a member of the backup-group. If I connect to the directory in stead of the dictionary I can even start a backup but get a lot of errors, cause I don't have access to the tables. I have to be sure about de ADSSYS pwd.

Answer (score 0):

As the `adsbackup.exe` tool basically just runs the sp_BackupDatabase / sp_BackupFreeTables stored procedures, you can easily replace it with the newer `asqlcmd.exe` tool:

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html?master_sql_command_line_switches.htm

Maybe you have more luck with the command line switches there.

On the other hand you say that you don't have an adssys password. First of all this is a big security risk!

I don't know if it is possible, but maybe you can add a second user for backup purposes that has a password. That way you could circumvent the password problem with `adsbackup.exe`.

Another approach would be to write your own tool in any language supported by ADS. If you have a talented programmer at hand that shouldn't be a big deal.

Finally I have another idea: Have you tried quoting your empty password with single or double quotes? Maybe the `adsbackup.exe` tool does quote processing and / or trimming on the password switch. You could also try passing a quoted string that contains of one or more white space characters.

Comment: Big thank you Jens, I will try this out. Btw, the database belongs to an LOB-application, for which I can't (and am not allowed to) set the password.